# How to make function as Directive and I have to use that in other components

Tags: html, css, angular

How to make function as Directive and I have to use that in other components.
Right now it is in one component but I have to use that in other components also.

```js
onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) 
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); 

      reader.onload = (event) => { 
        this.myprofile.Photo = event.target['result'];
        
      }
    }
```

```html
<input #inputFile type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input [funCtionDirective]="@someValues@" type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

you can create one custom directive and pass the necessary value to it like above. and then you can access it via `@Input`  decorator in that directives call